# Android email intent chooser doesnt work on some email clients

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When attaching a file to an email intent and using createChooser() I cant get the file to attach across all the email clients..then type I am using it

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://com.my.package/export.xml"));
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

It works on almost all email clients but not on the Yahoo email app.

How can I solve this?

Comment: this is irrelevant, it doesnt even mention email attachments on that thread :s i can send emails just fine the problem is with ATTACHING files and getting it to attach on every app

Comment: I'm sorry about the irrelevant link. I missed the Yahoo mail specific part of your question. I just tested it myself and I can confirm that Yahoo mail does not accept attachments through intents. A brief toast message pops up telling me `Read access denied: cannot read selected file`, even though the attached file is world-readable and located in the external storage. I assume that "Yahoo! Mail" does not open these `URI`s correctly (neither `content` nor `file` protocol works). I just sent them a bug report about that issue. Let's see what they have to say.

Comment: I just got a response from the "Yahoo! Mail" development team. They confirmed the issue as a bug and they told me that the next update of their app will be fixed.

Comment: thanks for that Nobu Games I really appreciate your efforts,perhaps you can put an answer below and I will mark it as correct